# Как выполнить команду Git, не находясь в хранилище?

Tags: git

Есть ли способ выполнить команды Git для хранилища, не находясь в этом хранилище, и при этом не используя команду cd?
Например, что-то вроде этого: `git /home/repo log`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для работы с репозиторием вне рабочего дерева можно указывать нахождение директории .git

```
git --git-dir=/home/repo/.git log
```